# RSS loop for importing images suddenly breaks down

Tags: php, image, rss, foreach

I'm using this code to import images from a rss news feed.

```
$source_xml = simplexml_load_file("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml");
foreach ($source_xml->channel->item as $rss) {
    $namespace      = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
    $images         = $rss->children($namespace)->thumbnail[1]->attributes();
    $image          = $images['url'];
    echo $image; echo "<br />";
}
```

The code seems to be working, however at some point in the loop, it just stops! The loop never goes through the whole rss feed. I tried to find out why it stops, but I just don't seem to get anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: because every rss feed get refreshed when the site update some results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in ...`

`$rss->children($namespace)->thumbnail[1]->attributes()` is empty for some line and you got fatal error.

Try this:

```
$source_xml = simplexml_load_file("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml");
foreach ($source_xml->channel->item as $rss) {
    $namespace      = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
    if(!is_object($rss->children($namespace)->thumbnail[1]))continue;
    $images         = $rss->children($namespace)->thumbnail[1]->attributes();
    $image          = $images['url'];
    echo $image; echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: thank you narek, this saved my life! by the way: sorry for asking this, but how did you find the fatal error?

Comment: @TomiSeus probably your error reporting is 0, add before foreach `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, it needs to help:)